# IllegalAccessException: cannot access class C (in module M) because module M does not export C to module N

Tags: java, maven, javafx

I'm trying to add Maven support to an existing JavaFX project that I have.

I started by following OpenJFX's [Getting Started Guide](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/#IDE-Intellij), which teaches you how to compile and run a Hello World JavaFX application with Maven. After I made it, I pasted my project's files in this new project and made the changes needed. My folder strucutre is more or less like this:

```
src/main/
  java/
    org.openjfx/
      Main.java
      components/
      controllers/
  resources/org.openjfx/fxml/
```

To run the project, I use these Maven commands:

```
compiler:compile
javafx:compile
javafx:run
```

However, I'm getting this error:

Exception in Application start method
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement (in module javafx.fxml) cannot access class org.openjfx.controllers.LoginController (in module org.openjfx) because module org.openjfx does not export org.openjfx.controllers to module javafx.fxml

Which seems odd, since apparently I'm exporting the stuff in `module-info.java`:

```java
module org.openjfx {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires javafx.fxml;

    opens org.openjfx to javafx.fxml;
    exports org.openjfx;
}
```

I wonder if naming my package `org.openjfx` was a bad idea and may be causing issues, but I just followed along with the tutorial.

Below is my `pom.xml` file, if it's of any relevance:

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
    <artifactId>hellofx</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
        <javafx.version>13</javafx.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>${maven.compiler.release}</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.openjfx.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: It looks like your controllers (for example) are in a subpackage of your main package. I believe you need to explicitly open that subpacakge in order for `javafx.fxml` to be able to access it via reflection: i.e. add  `opens org.openjfx.controllers to javafx.fxml;` to module-info.java.

Comment: Hell yeah, that works! I tried adding `exports org.openjfx.controllers` before, but it didn't work out. This works just smoothly. Thanks a lot! If you add this as an answer I'll be glad to accept it.

Comment: Just to note, I wouldn't use `org.openjfx` as your module name or package root (unless, of course, you're writing code for OpenJFX).

Comment: I'm not. I just followed along with the tutorial because I didn't know exactly what I was doing. What would be a more suitable naming? `com.project-name`?

Comment: Well, it's not really important for a personal project (outside of JPMS restrictions, e.g. no split-packages). If you ever write a library or application that you share with the world, however, the idea is to pick a unique group-id/artifact-id and use that to derive your root package name. The group-id/artifact-id  concept comes from Maven, I believe. There is already existing information out there advising how to choose appropriate values. That said, since this is a personal project and you're attempting to learn JavaFX I would ignore what I said for now and focus on more important things.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `javafx.fxml` module instantiates controller classes, and accesses fields and methods in them, via reflection. In order for that to work, you need to `open` the specific package(s) containing any controllers to the `javafx.fxml` module.

[This](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html) is a good resource for understanding the module system. Quoting from it:

> **open, opens, and opens…to.** Before Java 9, reflection could be used to learn about all types in a package and all members of a type—even
> its private members—whether you wanted to allow this capability or
> not. Thus, nothing was truly encapsulated.
>
> A key motivation of the module system is strong encapsulation. By
> default, a type in a module is not accessible to other modules unless
> it’s a public type and you export its package. You expose only the
> packages you want to expose. With Java 9, this also applies to
> reflection.
>
> ...
>
> **Allowing runtime-only access to a package by specific modules.** An opens…to module directive of the form
>
> ```
> opens package to comma-separated-list-of-modules
> ```
>
> indicates that a
> specific package’s public types (and their nested public and protected
> types) are accessible to code in the listed modules at runtime only.
> All of the types in the specified package (and all of the types’
> members) are accessible via reflection to code in the specified
> modules.

Note that you open *packages*, not *modules*. Since your controllers are in the sub-package `org.openjfx.controllers` (and I do think you should change your base package name), you need to explicitly open that sub-package (and possibly others).

Thus, adding

```
opens org.openjfx.controllers to javafx.fxml ;
```

to your `module-info.java` file should fix the problem

Comment: I was almost giving up on adding Maven. Your help was very important. Thanks a lot man!